# Can I graft a zone 10 tree's scion onto a zone 6 tree's rootstock?

Tags: fruit-trees, grafting, plant-hardiness

I want to grow pomegranates outdoors in Souther Ontario (Canada), and I am wondering if this would be possible by grafting a pomegranate scion onto an apple rootstock.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if it is would it survive a Canadian winter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this will not work. Grafting only works reliably between species/genera,and sometimes between families. Pomegranates are not closely related to apples, so this will not work.

Additionally, grafting onto hardy rootstock does not change the vulnerability to cold in the scion. The actual graft area will actually be more susceptible to cold than the rest of the plant.

See my very similar answer to a very similar question here:

- [Can I graft an orange tree to a hardier northern root stock?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13570/can-i-graft-an-orange-tree-to-a-hardier-northern-root-stock)